# Setting text color on all elements within div

Tags: javascript

I have a SCSS-mixin that looks like this:

```
/**
 * Text color
 */
@mixin text-color( $color ){
    color: $color;

    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5 {
        color: $color
    }

    p,
    li {
        color: $color;
    }

    a {
        color: $color;
        text-decoration: underline;

        &:hover {
            text-decoration: none;
        }
    }
}
```

It's not the nicest of things, but it's really handy. I use it, whenever the text color of some child-element is playing up. Every now and then, there is an `li` or an `a` that has some styling from further up the tree.

I'm looking for the JavaScript equivalent. The reason is, that I would like the user to select a hex-color, whereafter all elements will get that color.

My current version, is to do something like this (in a Vue-mixin):

```
mounted(){
  let chosenHex = #FF0000;
  this.setTextColorOnAllElements( chosenHex );
},
methods: {
  setTextColorOnAllElements( textColor ){
    setTimeout( () => { // Otherwise the el's aren't rendered
      this.setTextColorOnTagType( textColor, 'h1' );
      this.setTextColorOnTagType( textColor, 'h2' );
      this.setTextColorOnTagType( textColor, 'h3' );
      this.setTextColorOnTagType( textColor, 'h4' );
      this.setTextColorOnTagType( textColor, 'h5' );
      this.setTextColorOnTagType( textColor, 'h6' );
      this.setTextColorOnTagType( textColor, 'h7' );
      this.setTextColorOnTagType( textColor, 'p' );
      this.setTextColorOnTagType( textColor, 'li' );
      this.setTextColorOnTagType( textColor, 'span' );
      this.setTextColorOnTagType( textColor, 'a' );
    });
  },
  setTextColorOnTagType( textColor, tagType ){
    if( this.id ){
      let elements = document.querySelectorAll( '#' + this.id + ' ' + tagType );
      elements.forEach( (element) => {
        element.style.color = textColor;
      });
    }
  }

}
```

It's just long-winded and feels clumbsy.

---

### The overarching question:

What is a simple JavaScript function that sets the text color on all elements within a div?

---

Comment: You can separate multiple selectors in exactly the same way you do in CSS: with a comma. There’s potential for more optimization, but you’ll need to share some more details, e.g. what `#some-section` and the descendant elements may be. Do you really need the variables `h1s`, `h2s`, etc.? Prefer `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout`.

Comment: I don't need those variables, no. I was just one way to reach a solution. Whatever gets the job done. And why should I use `requestAnimationFrame` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Here to answer the overarching question.

Are you looking for something like this? Run the snippet.

```js
//use querySelectorAll to get all elements within the div
var children = document.querySelectorAll("div p")

//loop through those elements and change the color
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  children[i].style.color = "blue";
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <p>Lorem</p>
  <p>Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem</p>
  <p>Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem</p>
  <p>Ipsum</p>
  <p>Lorem</p>
  <p>Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

Alternatively, target the parent div to make it even easier:

```js
//use querySelector to target parent div
var parent = document.querySelector("div");

//set color on parent div to change color of children
parent.style.color = "blue";
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <h1>Lorem</h1>
  <h2>Ipsum</h2>
  <h3>Lorem</h3>
  <span>Ipsum</span>
  <li>Lorem</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not what you're looking for, but this technically works by virtue of creating and inserting a stylesheet.

```js
const forceColor = (selector, color) => {
  const rule = [
    `${selector} { color: ${color}; }`,
    ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'p', 'li'].map(
      v => `${selector} ${v}`
    ).join(', ') + ` { color: ${color}; }`,
    `${selector} a { color: ${color}; text-decoration: underline; }`,
    `${selector} a:hover { text-decoration: none; }`,
  ].join(' ');
  const css = document.createElement('style');
  css.type = 'text/css';
  css.styleSheet.cssText = rule;
  document.querySelector('head').appendChild(css);
};
```

You'd use it as such:

```js
forceColor('.someCSSSelector', '#FF0000');
```

Answer (score 1):

Note child elements color shouldnt have colors, its taken from parent div color

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const colorClassPicker = document.getElementById('colorClassPicker');
const colorHexPicker = document.getElementById('colorHexPicker');

const addClass = (className) => {
  container.classList.replace(container.classList.value, className);
};
const addStyle = (hex) => {
  container.style.color = hex;
};

// colorClassPicker.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
//   addClass(e.target.value);
// });
colorHexPicker.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  addStyle(e.target.value);
});

// addClass(colorClassPicker.value);
addStyle(colorHexPicker.value);
```

```css
h1,
h2,
h3,
a,
li,
p {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!-- Color classes
<select id="colorClassPicker">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</select> -->

Color hex
<select id="colorHexPicker">
  <option value="#e82830">#e82830</option>
  <option value="#690">#690</option>
  <option value="#2c28e8">#2c28e8</option>
</select>

<div class="container">
  <h1>H1</h1>
  <h1>H2</h1>
  <h1>H3</h1>
  <a href="">Link</a>
  <ul>
    <li>Lii</li>
    <li>Li2</li>
  </ul>
  <p>p</p>
</div>
```

Also you could do it by toggle classes in parent div

```
// colorClassPicker.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
//   addClass(e.target.value);
// });
```

Answer (score 0):

## Simple *oneliner* Javascript:

Try this:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("p").
    forEach(function(x){ x.style='color:brown;background:#CCC';});
```

```html
<h3>Head 1</h3><p>Paragraph 1</p><hr /><h3>Head 2</h3><p>Paragraph 2</p>
```

Or by:

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('p')).
    forEach(function(x){ x.style.color='brown';x.style.background='#CCC';});
```